# Load pre-selected values from database to selectize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using a JavaScript selectize to allow users to add multiple permissions when creating a role. This part wonderfully.

[image: Add permissions]

The challenge comes in when the user would like to edit a certain role. I would like to load the Selectize with the data that they had previously selected when creating the role. Here is my code;

Blade

```
<select id="permissions" name="permission[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="">Choose a permission</option>
   @foreach($permission as $value)
     <option value="{{ $value->name }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     $('#permissions').selectize();
   });
</script>
```

Currently, the selectize loads while empty and I am not sure how to tackle this challenge. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in_array function of php to check if the permission is already in selected permissions.

```
@foreach($permission as $value)
 <option {{in_array($value->name, $selectedPermissions) ? 'selected':''}} value="{{ $value->name }}">
    {{$value->name}} 
 </option>
@endforeach
```

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<select id="permissions" name="permission[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Choose a permission</option>
    @foreach($permission as $value)
        <option value="{{ $value->name }}" {{ (in_array($value->name, $permissionsArray)) ? 'selected' : '' }} {{ (collect(old('permission'))->contains($value->name)) ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ $value->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```